# jquery mobile css. change color

Tags: jquery-mobile

I use jquery mobile.I want to change the text color of a textarea html element when I put it with the disable option.

```
<textarea rows='6'  disabled  cols='60' id='"+results.rows.item(i).IdTypeCommentaire+"'  name='"+results.rows.item(i).LibelleTypeCommentaire+"'> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use CSS and work with the `disabled`selector:

```
textarea:disabled
{
color:#dddddd;
}
```

edit:
Just add it in your CSS or in the head section, like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  textarea:disabled
   {
   color:#dddddd;
   } 
</style>
```

Comment: without modify the css of jquery mobile file

Comment: your edit change the background i want to change the text color.

i add `color:red` ?

Comment: yep you got it - my bad, changed it.